# Is a local martingale with constant expectation necessarily a martingale?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

Suppose $X\in \mathbb R$ is a weak solution to the SDE $dX_t = \sigma(X_t)dW_t$, in which $W$ is a one-dimensional Brownian motion, and $\sigma$ is Borel measurable so that a weak solution exists and takes value in $(-\infty, \infty)$. In addition, suppose both boundaries $-\infty$ and $\infty$ are natural boundaries.

If $\mathbb E_x[X_t] =x$ for all $t\ge 0$, is it true that $X$ is necessarily a martingale?

If $X$ is nonnegative, then this is true because $X$ is a supermartingale. But I want to know whether we have a similar result in $(-\infty, \infty)$. Many thanks!

Comment: Revuz & Yor use the result that if expectation is constant over all stopping time taking on only 2 values it is a martingale, but is that not easy to show in this case with the markov property ?

Comment: Thanks michael. But I don't know whether $X$ has Markov property? It is probably a silly question.